# Where is my error in this visual basic Bubblesort

Tags: vba, sorting, visual-studio-2013, bubble-sort

I am currently making a highscore table - reading the times from a .csv file and sorting them from lowest to highest. The list only becomes partially sorted after the code runs.

All the data inputs correctly but when it goes to sort it sorts the data out incorrectly.

```
Private Sub BeginnerProcess(ByRef player() As pe_player, ByVal x As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim temp As Object

    For i = x To 0 Step -1
        For j = 0 To i - 1
            If player(j).playerTime > player(j + 1).playerTime Then
                temp = player(j)
                player(j) = player(j + 1)
                player(j + 1) = temp
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Dim k As Integer

    For k = 1 To x
        player(k).position = k
    Next

End Sub
```

Here's the output
[Leaderboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsVCK.png)

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in a debugger and looked for where the problem occurs?

Comment: Yeah I can't find the error with a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the classic bubble-sort to your case, I think i should be something like the code below:

```
For i = 0 To x - 1
    For j = i + 1 To x
        If player(i).playerTime > player(j).playerTime Then
            temp = player(i)
            player(i) = player(j)
            player(j) = temp
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: @A.Colver did you try the code above in my answer ?

Comment: I did try it I am still getting the same result though.

Comment: what is `player` ? Class array ? what type is it ?

Comment: player is a 99 index array of a structure defined as `Structure pe_player
        Dim position As Integer
        Dim playerName As String
        Dim playerTime As String
        Dim difficulty As String
    End Structure`

Comment: @A.Colver that's tough to bubble-sort :)

Comment: It was taking the first character and sorting it on the value of that

Comment: It's always the simplest errors that are hardest to find :D